# What happens if the Reapers catch me while I'm scanning?

Tags: mass-effect-3

On the system map, I can use the Normandy to scan for interesting items within the system.  However, scanning too much draws the ire of the Reapers.  They'll chase you back out of the system if this happens.

So far I've always ran like hell.  What happens if they catch me?  Do I get a game over?  Do I lose resources temporarily or permanently?  Do I get to fight them (and perhaps gain bonus XP or other benefits?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a critical mission failure and have to choose to exit, load or resume/"try again"-just like if you died on a mission.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NonstandardGameOver

Comment: Keep in mind, most travel around the map auto-saves, so you rarely ever really lose much, except maybe the other resources you collected in the same sector, if you 'die' this way.